# hardcoded address in disassembly

Tags: c++, assembly, shellcode

I'm writing optimized Windows based shellcode in C++ and I have problem avoiding hardcoded addresses in C++ while passing it to function.

e.g:

```
My_CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&thread_callback, NULL, NULL, NULL);

DWORD WINAPI thread_callback(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // stuff..
}
```

in disassembly, it shows CreateThread(..., cardcoded_address, ..);
instead, I want to pass this address like "from this location to thread_callback"

is there any way to avoid it? (because shellcode should be address independent?)

Regards.

Comment: If you are using a gcc-family compiler use -fPIC

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012.
EDIT: why I deserved downvotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, I was searching/doing some stuff and the final thing I've could done is that you can solve this with delta offset.

Explanation: at the very first function of your code, there should be function like this:

```
DWORD delta;

__asm {
    call GetBasePointer
    GetBasePointer:
    pop eax
    sub eax, GetBasePointer
    mov [delta], eax
}
```

You can also google for delta offset for more details.
Afterwards, you can do something like this:

```
My_CreateThread(NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)((DWORD)thread_callback + (DWORD)delta), NULL, NULL, NULL);

DWORD WINAPI thread_callback(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    // stuff..
}
```

and it will work fine,

Regards.

Comment: But `delta` is a location in memory with an absolute address, so you have the same problem with it

Comment: Well, I don't know about which absolute address you mean, but whenever I tested at random locations, thread executed fine without exceptions.

Comment: The instruction `mov [delta],eax` generates a move to an absolute address.

Comment: @mcleod_ideafix: It shouldn't... it should be indexed from ESP.

Comment: Why? Is it a local variable? Oh well, then it is indexed from EBP

Comment: Yes, everything I'm using there is locally defined variables.